# Wireless stops immediately after I log in Ubuntu 12.04 LTS on Lenovo IdeaPad Z710

Tags: 12.04, wireless, lenovo, ideapad

Wireless stops immediately after I log in Ubuntu 12.04 LTS on Lenovo IdeaPad Z710.
I need a little help.
Thank you in advance.
nm-tool gives me State: disconnected

Answer (score 0):

Your wireless might be disabled, run the following commands in the terminal (ctrl+alt+t):

1. `iwconfig` this will output the name of your wireless card, it's
   usually **wlan0**
2. Assuming the name was wlan0, run `ifconfig wlan0 up`, if the name is
   not wlan0 the replace it for the correct one.

I hope this helps, good luck.

Comment: After I run iwconfig it shows me this : eth0 no wireless extensions. and lo no wireless extensions.

Comment: Try doing the following:
1 - `sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic` 2 - 
`sudo apt-get install --reinstall bcmwl-kernel-source` 3 - `sudo modprobe wl` 4 - `iwconfig` After the last command close the terminal and log off and back in.

Comment: I plugged the ethernet cable, did all these steps, plugged off the cable but it still appears that Disconnected error..  Still not working.

Comment: Let's take a step back and actually identify your wireless device first: lspci -nn | grep 0280

Comment: Network controller :  Intel Corporation Wireless 7260 (Rev 73)

Comment: I installed the latest driver , but still not working.